# DocuSign API: issues sending as a different user with multiple recipients

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusignconnect

UPDATE: our business logic uses the pause_before workflowStep (which the webhooks do businessy stuff then unpause). the user who created the envelope MUST be the same user who calls unpause.

SUGGESTION for devs: calling envelopesApi.update() should throw an error if the update doesn't work in this scenario. instead, it returns the same success as a *real* success. thanks :)

I am trying to send an envelope with multiple recipients as a different user on my company account.

I set up OAuth consent for JWT (https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent) and can successfully send from any of our users. Note - we are currently using the "individual consent url" method.

The issue is that our envelopes have multiple recipients and only the first recipient gets an email.

I have confirmed the behavior in multiple ways:

1. the envelope does all our fancy stuff when sending as the main accountId
2. we have several webhooks set up to fire on recipient sent and recipient complete ... when on the main accountId, we see expected sent-completed-sent-completed-etc pattern ... but when sending as any other user, we only see a sent-completed for the first recipient
3. when looking at the inbox (https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents) and clicking on an individual envelope ... on the main accountId, I can see all users under recipients as well as all the recipients when expanding the signing order diagram ... on any other user, all the recipients past the first one are missing BUT they all still appear under the signing order diagram (same as the main accountId envelope)
4. I have put our code into debug mode and paused before sending the envelope ... both ways look nearly identical. the only differences are the accessToken and accountId (I even tried with the obtained access token for the individual user and accountId for the main user. same result)

Relevant info:

- Running in node.js
- using npm docusign-esign (5.8.1) to connect to docusignApi
- everything was setup using docusign connect
- currently building app on docusign demo account
- I have tried manually unpausing the envelope just to see what would happen. no dice

My $$$ is on some docusign setting for individual users beyond just granting consent to send as them. The biggest flag for me is #3 - the other recipients are missing from the envelope BUT still appear on the signing order diagram (email and all). How is this possible??

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see your code but I wonder if you have **routingOrder** like 1, 2, 3 such that only the first recipient gets to sign first and only then the second one would get the email?

Other option is that you added **clientUserId** for embedded signing, that would suppress the email messages.

Yet another option is the envelope workflow was [paused](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/pause-workflow/) after the first user and it has to be [unpaused](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/unpause-workflow/) for the next email to go out.

Comment: thanks for your response!

after further examination ... the issue seems to be that we are adding a pauseBefore step.

I have learned that the user to unpause MUST be the same user which created the workflow :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize you're using the pause feature. I'll add it to the answer. Please mark it as resolved.

Comment: Nice! Yeah I didn’t think the pause would be relevant since the only change in the two JSONs sent was the accessToken and accountId. Obviously I was mistaken :) One idea, should the envelopesApi.update() function throw an error if the update won’t do anything (e.g. wrong user)?

Comment: Im not sure. this is a relatively new feature and I have not tried your edge-case. Feel free to ask another question if you need more help.